# Reading a series of CSV files containing mixed content into Python for data analysis

Tags: python, list, csv

Thanks for reading.
I decided to build a "workbench" for testing trading systems. I have the open, high, low, close, and volume for my favorite 600 stocks by minute for the past year plus. The goal is to read files in, calculate trade indicators based on the pricing data, and simulate trades, and finally wind up with a theoretical profit for a day, week, hour, month, whatever. All the pricing data is in CSV files with comma delimiters, example: 3/14/2020,10:23:00,82.00,84.06,81.50,82.02,58900. No spaces between data, and no line end marker. Total, I am looking at around 60 million records as each file has around 100K records. My biggest problem is getting the records into a file with some kind of an index so I can average the third, fourth, and fifth elements, average the volume over 24 minute time periods, etc. I am an experienced COBOL, and RPG programmer but the times, they are a changing.
Many thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, "content" has the shape of the content of one of the files:

```
content = """date,hour,open,high,low,close,volume
3/14/2020,10:23:00,82.00,84.06,81.50,82.02,58900
4/14/2020,10:23:00,1.00,2.06,3.50,4.02,500"""
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content))
print(df)
        date      hour  open   high   low  close  volume
0  3/14/2020  10:23:00  82.0  84.06  81.5  82.02   58900
1  4/14/2020  10:23:00   1.0   2.06   3.5   4.02     500
```

If that is the case, you can read one file with

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

(change "file.csv" with the real name).

If you need to read not just a file, but a folder

```
import glob, os    
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', ".csv"))))
```

And will save all the csv files in df.

Anyway, the average/mean is just:

```
print(df.mean())
open         41.50
high         43.06
low          42.50
close        43.02
volume    29700.00
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Clarifications: Each file is the minute-by-minute history for one stock for one year, about 100K lines of (date, time, open, hi, lo, close, vol), oldest first. I need to read lines one at a time, process them, read the next line. etc. This simulates the minute-by-minute data feed from the broker. When a line is read, trading indicators are calculated (from that line and potentially some previous data) and a possible buy or sell order is issued, the next line is read, processed, etc. I am trying to create a simulation to do the backtesting to determine the best strategies.